# What can I say about the function $f$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, open-map

> > Let $X= \left \{(x_i)_{i \geq 1} : x_i \in \{0,1 \}\ \text {for all}\ i \geq 1 \right \}$ with the metric $d \left ( (x_i),(y_i)  \right ) = \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} \frac {|x_i-y_i|} {2^i}.$ Let $f: X \longrightarrow [0,1]$ be the function defined by $f(x_i)_{i \geq 1} = \sum\limits_{i \geq 1 } \frac {x_i}{2^i}.$ Then which one of the following statement/s is/are correct?
> >
> > $(1)$ $f$ is onto.
> >
> > $(2)$ $f$ is open.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: What I observed is that $$f \left (B_d( (x_i)_{i \geq 1}; r \right )) \subseteq B_u \left ( \sum\limits_{i \geq 1} \frac {x_i} {2^i};r \right ).$$

Comment: Is the reverse equality also valid? Then $f$ will be open. Right? What about onto case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of whether $f$ is onto does not depend on the  metric assigned.

Clearly the restriction of $f$ to the range $[0,1)$ is onto because and real number in $[0,1)$ can be represented as a (possibly unending) sequence of bits, and that is a member of $X$.  So the onto issue comes down to whether there is any $x \in X$ such that $f(X) = 1$.  And indeed the member $(x_i)_{i \geq 1 1} : \forall i x_i = 1$ has the property that $f(x) = \sum_{i \geq 1} 2^{-i} = 1$.  Therefore, $f$ is onto.

The issue of whether $f$ is open becomes the question of whether the image of every open set under the peculiar metric $d$ is also an is an open set under the familiar metric defined by $f$.  The latter open sets are the ordinary familiar open sets within $(0,1)$.

Comment: How do I show that any element of $(0,1)$ is in the image of $f$?

Comment: The definition of $f(\{x_i\})$ exactly corresponds to the definition of the binary number represented by the sequence $\{x_i\}$ written after the "decimal point." Those binary numbers represent the whole real line interval from 0 to 1.

Comment: Got it @Mark Fischler. Thanks for your kind help.